# How to protect the refresh token from hacker

Tags: security, spring-security, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I googled a lot on how to protect the `refresh_token` from a hacker because it will be stored somewhere in browser's `local-storage`/`cookie`, so a hacker can easily steal those tokens and I couldn't able to find a proper answer so I came here.

I understand that `access_token` will expire in less-time and we should use `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token`. But if the hackers steal the `refresh_token` means, he can stay as a login user for a long time, right?

Some people are saying, you can protect it using `client_id` and `client_secret`, but the hacker is going to access the endpoint of the API, which has the `client_id` and `client_secret`. So again, a hacker can get a new access_token easily.

So I am finding no way to protect the hacker from getting the new `access_token`.

Can someone able to guide me here, on how I protect the hacker from getting access to refresh token from browser's `local-storage`/`cookie`?

Comment: @dur I have to have refresh_token, else the user will be logged out so often.
How authorization grant type is different from not password grant type.

Comment: Password grant type is not recommended. Too many security issues.

Answer (score 1):

From the context of your explanation, you are talking about a browser based application. If this application is one that does not have a backend, then you do not have a secure place to store your long-lived tokens or client secrets.

From OAuth 2.0 perspective, these are called [public clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1). Thus protocol do not allow them to have a client secret. So they have a client ID and a redirect URL for client authentication (client identification). Implicit flow is one key flow suitable for SPA that runs on browser. By specification, they will not get a refresh token. Reason is their inability to protect such secrets.

But if you have a backend and have the ability to correlate browser session and backend storage, you can use a flow that gives your a refresh token and store it securely. But this require your application architecture to support such (ex:- Browser session and backend storage).

Also, rather than making end user to login every time, you may use the identity server's logged in state to skip log in. This too will rely on identity server's browser cookie and it's life time. For example identity server may have a browser session valid for 24hours. So your client will not see log in page when accessed thew application within the time.

Comment: My application has the backend. After successful login, I am sending refresh_token also in the response, which is quite visible and easy for anyone to hack. So how to send the refresh_token securely from the back-end, also how the front-end can store that refresh_token securely.

Comment: @SuganthanMadhavanPillai having a backend is great. That means you can use authorization code flow. Can't you obtain token response from backend ? For example through a servlet that receive authorization code response ? If that's possible you will not have to resend refresh token to backend. Your front end simply require to get access token if front end directly contact APIs

Answer (score 0):

You can try to secure the local storage using this library [Secure-ls](https://github.com/softvar/secure-ls)